# cutting certain lengths of the string in csv file and adding it in quotes followed by a comma

Tags: shell, unix, csv, sed

I have a csv file like

```
PC1234  
PC4567
PC7890
```

one below another

i am trying using shell script to cut the first 6 values alone as they would be accompanied by several gaps(spaces).I have tried the below.

```
cat Upd_Master_Payloads.csv | while read line           
do 
  interface=`expr $line|cut -c 1-6`

echo "$interface" > INPUT.csv
done

chmod 777 INPUT.csv
sed "s/.*/'&'/" INPUT.csv | tr '\n' ',' > SQL_INPUT.csv

chmod 777 SQL_INPUT.csv
```

i am able to do so for only the first line and not the other lines..

please help as i am new to shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you keep overwriting the entire file with `> INPUT.csv`. Try using `>> INPUT.csv` to append to the file instead.

Alternatively, a better way to write the loop is:

```
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    interface=${line:0:6}
    echo "$interface"
done < Upd_Master_Payloads.csv > INPUT.csv
```

Comment: Or even just `cut -c1-6 Upd_Master_Payloads.csv > INPUT.csv`... Not sure if using a loop to process line-by-line really gains anything here...